# JavaFX PropertyValueFactory for values of a HashMap

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I am currently developing a program where you have a table. There, the columns should be variable. This means that depending on what you specify, many columns will be created. I have implemented this:

```
public void setAlph(String alphString){
    ArrayList<Character> alphNew = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (char c : alphString.toCharArray()) {
        alphNew.add(c);
    }
    alph = alphNew;
    alph.add('#');
    for(int i = 0; i < states.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < alph.size(); j++){
            states.get(i).addChar(alph.get(j));
        }
    }
    mainWindowController.getTableRules().getColumns().clear();
    TableColumn statesCol = new TableColumn("state");
    statesCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<State, String>("name"));
    mainWindowController.getTableRules().getColumns().addAll(statesCol);
    for(int i = 0; i < getAlph().size(); i++){
        TableColumn tc = new TableColumn("" + getAlph().get(i));
        tc.setCellValueFactory(new MapValueFactory<String>("" + getAlph().get(i)));
        mainWindowController.getTableRules().getColumns().addAll(tc);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I do not know how to insert values into the columns now.
The class "State" (where the values come from) looks like this:

```
public class State {

private final SimpleStringProperty name;
private Map<Character, String> map;

public State(String name) {
    this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
    map = new HashMap<Character, String>();
}

public String getName() {
    return name.get();
}

public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name.set(name);
}

public String toString(){
    return name.get();
}

public void addChar(char c){
    map.put(c, "null");
}

public String getValue(char key){
    return map.get(key);
}
```

}

Now I want values from the HashMap to be put into the column. Only I do not really know how to do that: /. Could someone help me please?
Thank you in advance!
lg bttl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats the Solution:

```
for(int i = 0; i < getAlph().size(); i++){
        final int j = i;
        TableColumn tc = new TableColumn("" + getAlph().get(i));
        tc.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<State,String>,ObservableValue<String>>(){
            public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<State, String> param) {
                return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().mapPropertyProperty().get(getAlph().get(j)));
            }
        });
        mainWindowController.getTableRules().getColumns().addAll(tc);
    }
```

Comment: i was exactly looking for this, thanks for posting your solution